# Join two tables field based on the same id?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

Need a help joining two tables based on the same id.

Table 1:

```
id_1 | id_2
```

Table 2:

```
id | name
```

I need a query where looks for id_1 on table 2 field id and return the field name and also looks for id_2 on table 2 field id and return the field name.

An example would be:

Table 1:

```
1 | 2
```

Table 2:

```
1 | Joe
2 | Michael
```

Return would be:

```
Joe | Michael
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
select t21.name, t22.name
from Table1 t1 
inner join Table2 t21 on t1.id_1 = t21.id
inner join Table2 t22 on t1.id_2 = t22.id
```